# Comparing numerical elements in a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I've a list of lists that include both a numerical value and a string value

An example of this list would be:

```
really_big_list = [
    [
        ["A",1], ["B",2], ["C",3]
    ], 
    [
        ["A",2], ["G",2], ["C", 5]
    ], 
    [
        ["A", 2], ["B", 5], ["D", 3]
    ]
]
```

What I want to achieve is to check the first elements that exist in all the lists and if they do between eachother, then get the porcentual change of the numeric value in the second row of the list.

I've already done this process by iterating over all the lists, but this takes a gigantic amount of time to accomplish, I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this. Maybe Pandas would be a great fit, but I don't have much experience using it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "if they do between each other".  Could you include the specific output you'd be looking for in this example and/or the code you're using to get that result?  Does the fact that it's a list of lists even matter, or are you just aggregating all of the lowest level lists regardless of which sublist they appear in?

Comment: every solution will require iterating over the list in *some way*. So in any case, it isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do. So you *really* must elaborate. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do this.  I would convert your list of lists to a list of dicts, since that lets Python do the searching.

Then, I'd use a Counter to count how many times each key occurs.  If a key occurs the same number of times as the length of the list, then it must be in every row:

```
really_big_list = [
    [
        ["A",1], ["B",2], ["C",3]
    ], 
    [
        ["A",2], ["G",2], ["C", 5]
    ], 
    [
        ["A", 2], ["B", 5], ["D", 3]
    ]
]

# Convert to list of dicts.

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()
rbl = []

for row in really_big_list:
    counts.update(k[0] for k in row)
    rbl.append( dict(row) )

print(counts)
pick,count = counts.most_common(1)[0]
assert count == len(rbl)
print(f"Here are all the entries for {pick}:")
for row in rbl:
    print(row[pick])
```

Output:

```
Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'G': 1, 'D': 1})
Here are all the entries for A:
1
2
2
```